# Получить часы и минуты в часовом поясе UTC

Tags: javascript

В переменной `this.x` содержится timestamp в миллисекундах.
Задача - вывести время в формате `'h:i'`. Проблема в том, что при выводе время отображается в часовом поясе клиента. Но мне нужно так, что бы время было строго в часовом поясе UTC.

```
var date = new Date(this.x);
return  '<b>Время:</b> ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes();
```

Comment: ```date.getUTCHours()``` и ```date.getUTCMinutes()```, - вы про это?

Comment: @gregzakharov, да, то что нужно! спасибо! 
Может быть, можете подсказать как сделать так что бы часы и минуты были с ведущим нулём?

Comment: `('0' + date.getUTCHours()).slice(-2)` и `('0' + date.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2)`

Comment: @RomanAndreev, ```[d.getUTCHours(), d.getUTCMinutes()].map(x => {return ('0' + x).slice(-2)}).join(':')```